# How to remove One Item from session array in Laravel 8

Tags: session, laravel-8

**i have create a session array like this:**

```
public function addToCart($id, $qty){
    $cart = session('Hami__cart');
    $cart[$id] = ['quantity'=>$qty, 'color'=>'default', 'size'=>'default', 'id'=>$id];
     session()->put('Hami__cart',$cart);
}
```

[i have add 2 entries in this session it's look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVuEF.png)

**Now I want to remove one item from this array i am trying this code but it doesn't work  :**

```
public function RemoveCartItem($id){
        $items = session('Hami__cart');        
        if($items != ""){
            foreach ($items as $key => $values){
                if($key == $id ){
                    session()->forget($items[$key]);
                }
              }
        }
    }
```

How to remove one item from this Session Array, i have also try unset() but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function RemoveCartItem($id){
    $items = session('Hami__cart');        
        if($items != ""){
            foreach ($items as $key => $values){
                if($key == $id ){
                    unset($items[$key]);
                }

            }
          session()->put('Hami__cart', $items);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).